# Numbering each row in a ListView (C#)

Tags: c#, listview

REVISED: I have a Windows Forms Application and have added a ListView. I am able to add items to my list view, but I am wanting to number each row that has an item. I want those numbers to appear in column 2.

```
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int initialID = 2;

            //Change button text.
            button4.Text = ("Clear/Add Fonts");

            //For each string in the open file dialog array.
            foreach (string fontFileName in ofd.SafeFileNames)
            {
                //Add a line in the list view for each selected file. Don't allow for the same file to appear twice.
                if (listView1.FindItemWithText(fontFileName) == null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < initialID; i++)
                        listView1.Items.Add(fontFileName).SubItems.Add((i).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Sorry of the change was somewhat dramatic after the revision. I now have the numbers appearing under the Font ID, but now I can't seem to get it to increment. I think I'm very close.

***Answer:***
Here is how I implemented the suggestions by Cyral:

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                int initialID = 1;
                int count = initialID;

                //Change button text.
                button4.Text = ("Clear/Add Fonts");

                //For each string in the open file dialog array.
                foreach (string fontFileName in ofd.SafeFileNames)
                {
                    //Add a line in the list view for each selected file. Don't allow for the same file to appear twice.
                    if (listView1.FindItemWithText(fontFileName) == null)
                    {
                            listView1.Items.Add(fontFileName).SubItems.Add(count++.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
```

Comment: `lvi` doesn't seem to be attached to anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old Question:**

You need to set the `SubItems` on the `ListViewItem` you just added.

```
lvi.Text = fontFileName;
lvi.SubItems.Add(initialID.ToString());
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

**New Question:**

Your counter loop will not work because it resets each time, and because your `InitialID` is one, `i` will always be 0.

I suggest using the following:

```
int initialID = 1; //Make a constant and put it somewhere
int count = initialID; //Will count how many items are added (Could also be done with a for loop with a condition)
foreach (string fontFileName in ofd.SafeFileNames)
{
    //Add a line in the list view for each selected file. Don't allow for the same file to appear twice.
    if (listView1.FindItemWithText(fontFileName) == null)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(fontFileName);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(i.ToString());
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to clean up a few things in the code. I accomplished the subitem task in one line: `listView1.Items.Add(fontFileName).SubItems.Add((i).ToString());`

I'm working on the incrementation now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Got it! I added the final code to my original post under "Answer." I really appreciate your help. Being new I tend to attract a lot of arrogance. Some people just edit my grammar. Ugh.